# Trouble with java google quickstart tutorial "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.plus.samples.quickstart. Signin"

Tags: java, google-plus

Im having trouble with the java google quickstart tutorial at https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/java Im currently at step **3.2**
but whenever i run the

```
java -classpath "bin:lib/*" com.google.plus.samples.quickstart.Signin
```

I get the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/plus/sampl
es/quickstart/Signin
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.plus.samples.quickstart. Signin
```

Im running this under C:\Users\myname\Desktop\gplus-quickstart-java-master>

Anyone who used the tutorial before encountered this error? How can I resolve this?  Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: This question seems to have nothing to do with the google-app-engine tag.  ClassNotFound often means File Not Found.

Comment: can you try with `java -classpath "bin;lib/*" com.google.plus.samples.quickstart.Signin`

Comment: @RC thanks that did the job!  Google needs to update this tutorial.  You can post this as an answer and I will accept it sir.  Thanks again.

Comment: Done. I will report to Google ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `java -classpath "bin;lib/*" com.google.plus.samples.quickstart.Signin` because `;` is the correct path separator under Windows.